# Issue with web application using JSP and Hibernate

Tags: html, hibernate, jsp

Below is my index.html and action.jsp code
When I am submitting the values from index.html to action.jsp instead of getting the output of out.println in action.jsp I am getting the complete action.jsp as my output. [image: output of the code]

Advise what is the issue and how to rectify it also advise if the directory structure is correct i.e.; all files are placed where they are usually supposed to be placed or not [image: Directory Structure]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="action.jsp" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name = "name"> <br>
    Password <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

// Below is action.jsp

<%@page import="p1.NewHibernateUtil"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Transaction"%>
<%@page import="p1.User"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%
          out.println("In scriplet tag");
          Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
          out.println("Configuration object created");
          cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
          out.println("Configured");

//            SessionFactory sf = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
//            out.println("SessionFactory created");
//            Session ses = sf.openSession();
//            Transaction t = ses.beginTransaction();
//            String n = request.getParameter("name");
//            String p = request.getParameter("password");
//            
//           out.println("Welcome " + n);
//            User u1 = new User(n, p);
//            ses.save(u1);
//            t.commit();
//            ses.close();
//            out.println("Data inserted successfully");



     %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show us what are you getting as message at the console !!

Comment: 2017-01-09T13:00:08.633+0530|Info: visiting unvisited references
2017-01-09T13:00:08.887+0530|Info: visiting unvisited references
2017-01-09T13:00:08.893+0530|Info: visiting unvisited references
2017-01-09T13:00:09.139+0530|Info: Loading application [Website] at [/Website]
2017-01-09T13:00:09.175+0530|Info: Website was successfully deployed in 558 milliseconds.

Also I have update my directory structure in question, kindly have a look and advise if all the files (Eg: .jsp,.html) are where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

As per my assumption you are running the given example without using **web server**. You will require web server to run given code.

Consider using web server (ex. Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/index.html )

Comment: I am using glassfish server and I can see the application(project) in Glassfish Management in deployed application.

Also I have update my directory structure in question, kindly have a look and advise if all the files (Eg: .jsp,.html) are where they are supposed to be